# How to reset openshift deployment to a new state?

Tags: openshift

I have an openshift application and I radically redesigned the app locally and want to start fresh on the openshift server.

I could delete all the gears and redo them but is there a elegant way or any way to just fully reset an openshift application to it's default fresh state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found several answers.

1. rhc ssh yourAppName
2. rm -rf everything in /app-root/repo
3. rm -rf everything in the /git directory(ignore the errors)
4. cd into /git/yourAppName.git
5. git init --bare

There's also deployment management here:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-deployments.html
You can restore back to a pristine state.

I just wanted to know how to do it by hand.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to completely reset your git repository for your application you can follow these instructions (https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-erase-all-history-from-a-git-repository-on-openshift-and-start-over-with).  It's a little unclear what exactly you are trying to accomplish.  I would recommend adding more details about what you are trying to do.  Deleting and starting over is probably your best bet to "completely start over".

Answer (score 1):

Push the updated code to the server with Git. More info here:
https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-modifying-applications.html